# how to use onchange event in js separate file?

Tags: drop-down-menu

this is my select box. i want to know if i want to use this select box for onchange event so what is the scenario or what is the code which i write on it.

```
<select class="sortable" id="sorter">
       <option value="A-Z" class="asc">A-Z</option>
       <option value="Z-A" class="desc">Z-A</option>
  </select>
```

this is my js file. and please tell me the changes that wishs i do for calling the onchange event for this selection box. thanks in advance.

```
var table=function(){
    function sorter(n){
        this.n=n; this.t; this.b; this.r; this.d; this.p; this.w; this.a=[]; this.l=0
    }
    sorter.prototype.init=function(t,f){
        this.t=document.getElementById(t);
        this.b=this.t.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        this.r=this.b.rows; var l=this.r.length;
        for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
            if(i==0){
                var c=this.r[i].cells; this.w=c.length;
                for(var x=0;x<this.w;x++){
                    if(c[x].className!='nosort'){
                        c[x].className='head';
                        c[x].onchange=new Function(this.n+'.work(this.cellIndex)')
                    }
                }
            }else{
                this.a[i-1]={}; this.l++;
            }
        }
        if(f!=null){
            var a=new Function(this.n+'.work('+f+')'); a()
        }
    }
    sorter.prototype.work=function(y){
        this.b=this.t.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; this.r=this.b.rows;
        var x=this.r[0].cells[y],i;
        for(i=0;i<this.l;i++){
            this.a[i].o=i+1; var v=this.r[i+1].cells[y].firstChild;
            this.a[i].value=(v!=null)?v.nodeValue:''
        }
        for(i=0;i<this.w;i++){
            var c=this.r[0].cells[i];
            if(c.className!='nosort'){c.className='head'}
        }
        if(this.p==y){
            this.a.reverse(); x.className=(this.d)?'asc':'desc';
            this.d=(this.d)?false:true
        }else{
            this.p=y; this.a.sort(compare); x.className='asc'; this.d=false
        }
        var n=document.createElement('tbody');
        n.appendChild(this.r[0]);
        for(i=0;i<this.l;i++){
            var r=this.r[this.a[i].o-1].cloneNode(true);
            n.appendChild(r); r.className=(i%2==0)?'even':'odd'
        }
        this.t.replaceChild(n,this.b)
    }
    function compare(f,c){
        f=f.value,c=c.value;
        var i=parseFloat(f.replace(/(\$|\,)/g,'')),n=parseFloat(c.replace(/(\$|\,)/g,''));
        if(!isNaN(i)&&!isNaN(n)){f=i,c=n}
        return (f>c?1:(f<c?-1:0))
    }
    return{sorter:sorter}
}();
```